# How to find distance between colliding objects?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, distance

Consider an object A with mass m with velocity v collides with another resting object B with mass M. After colliding we know that after some time both the objects will gain same velocity. But a question comes what will be the distance covered in the time interval between B's initial rest to gained velocity. For reference here is a picture I've provided:

[image: The_image]

In the after collision section the dotted objects (left) were at the moment of collision and the clear objects (right) are at current position.

NOTE: The after collision velocity
of the objects were calculated using the conservation of momentum law.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the material of the two balls. A hard material such as glass may allow the balls to gain $\frac{mv}{m+M}$ velocity quickly and a soft material may allow the balls to gain that velocity more slowly, affecting the distance traveled. In theoretical physics problems, it's usually assumed that the inelastic collision happens instantaneously so the distance traveled would be 0 in this case.

Comment: Thanks pal . :D

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Idk how to do that . Lemme know . I am a newbie over here.

Comment: @DipanjanDas Hit the tick symbol under the answer. Please do so for any other answers you've recieved as well.